# How to compare arrays with different sizes

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference, array-intersect

I want to compare 2 arrays, except the two arrays may sometimes be of different sizes.

**For example, I have a form and I receive the values with this:**

```
// The post send more values than other array:
//   name , email , password, phone , address
// but in other cases send only one value and the other array it's bigger
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{    
    $fields_array[]=$key;    
}
```

**On the other side, I have this other array that I want to compare against:**

```
    $fields_compare=array("name","email");
```

In this case when the array called $fields_array is the larger one, I don't have a problem. However, if for example the second array is larger, I have problems.

**I continued and did this:**

```
$aa=array_diff($fields_array,$fields_compare);
$bb=array_intersect($fields_array,$fields_compare);

foreach ($aa as $aaa)
{
    // Show the others different values, no show name and email
    print "".$aaa."<br>";
}

foreach ($bb as bbb)
{
    // Show the same Values in this case the same will be name and email ///
    print "".$bbb."<br>";
}
```

All this works if the first array is larger, but in other cases it doesn't work and doesn't show the real differences.

Comment: You have foreach ($bb as bbb), it should be foreach ($bb as $bbb).

Comment: That error it´s because i writte the things here , i put right now , regards

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare (like, the actual data and expected results)? The behaviour depends upon what you want to do with the "excess" elements.

Comment: check for count and flip your equation

Comment: I have form , this form send values , in some cases this form can has 8 fields and in other cases can have 5 , the values save in other file of text , always i have 10 values but only i must change the values i want , if for example i send 8 values from form but only want change the values i put in the other array i must get the values same in both arrays and the other no change and continue with the same value

Comment: give two example data sets (contents of the arrays) so we can see what you are trying to compare

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but what about just testing the input value types as you loop through the POST'd values?

```
$fields_compare=array("name" => true, "email" => true); //faster than in_array( );
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{    
    if(isSet($fields_compare[$key]))
    {
        //do something (eg: save $value to text file)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes input post values , yes